# Problems restarting networking

Tags: networking, server, wireless, internet

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 Server computer that has a usb wifi dongle to establish wifi connection. The problem is that if I turn off and then on the router I lose internet connection. In that cases I tried this commands to re-establish connection : `sudo ifdown wlan0` and `sudo ifup wlan0`. Although with `ifconfig` I can see wlan0 interface, with the ip, gateway, netmask... I really don't have a wirelless connection. When I ifdown and ifup I don't get any error or warning .If I make a ping to 8.8.8.8 the output is:

> From 192.168.1.101 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable

I don't have any network manager, as Network-Manager, wicd or connman. Note that I have set a static ip in `\etc\network\interfaces` file:

> auto wlan1
>
> iface wlan1 inet static
>
> address 192.168.1.101
>
> netmask 255.255.255.0
>
> gateway 192.168.1.1
>
> wpa-ssid.......
>
> wpa-psk......
>
> dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1

The problem is only when router is restarted. If not the connection works perfectly.

**EDIT**

This is the output I get with `sudo ifdown wlan1 && sudo ifup -v wlan1`, I think is important:

```
Configuring interface wlan1=wlan1 (inet)                              
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d                          
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools          
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant           
wpa_supplicant: wpa-driver nl80211,wext (default)                     
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P
/var/run/wpa_supplicant.wlan1.pid -i wlan1 - D nl80211,wext -C
/var/run/wpa_supplicant                                               
Starting /sbin/wpa_supplicant...                                      
wpa_supplicant: waiting for "/var/run/wpa_supplicant.wlan1.pid":  0
(max. 5)               wpa_supplicant: creating sendsigs omission
pidfile: /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.wpa
_supplicant.wlan1.pid                                                                      wpa_supplicant: ctrl_interface socket located at
/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan1             wpa_supplicant: configuring
network block -- 0                                            
wpa_supplicant: wpa-ssid "*****" -- OK               
wpa_supplicant: wpa-psk ***** -- OK                                   
wpa_supplicant: enabling network block 0 -- OK                        
ip addr add 192.168.1.101/255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255       
dev wlan1 label  wlan1                                                
ip link set dev wlan1   up                                            
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1  dev wlan1                       
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d                              
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvconf               
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate                     
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/openssh-server              
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/upstart                     
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/wpasupplicant
```

However I still don't have connection although appears to work.

**EDIT2**

I have seen that after `sudo ifdown wlan1 && sudo ifup -v wlan1` the output of `route` changes from:

```
Kernel IP routing table                                                                   
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface             
default         Barinatxe-RUT24 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan1             
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0              
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan1
```

to:

```
Kernel IP routing table                                                                   
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface             
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan1             
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0              
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan1
```

Where `Barinatxe-RUT24` is the name of the router.

Thanks in advance, if any extra information is required ask please.

Comment: Is your interface wlan1 or wlan0? We are confused.

Comment: @chili555 is wlan1, sorry.

Comment: Is there a difference if you are using `sudo ifconfig wlan1 down && sleep 30 && sudo ifconfig wlan1 up` - usually it takes few seconds to `up` or `down` any interface.

Comment: @pa4080, same result, "destination host is unreachable". Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you connect if you change to DHCP? What address, gateway, etc. do you get?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @chili555 DHCP appears to dont' work, gets blocked on 'DHCPDISCOVER on wlan1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0x29ed5711) '  and finally says 'No DHCPOFFERS received.'

Comment: Any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep -e wlan -e wpa` Since the output may be lengthy post the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Also, is the wpa-psk specified double-checked? Case?

Comment: Here you have: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xNPTxTWbrJ/ @chili555

Comment: @chili555 I don't know much about linux, but appears that something in wrong...

Comment: I suggest that you try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243280/how-to-fix-deauthentication-by-local-choice

Comment: @chili555 are you suggesting to change Channel width and Auto channel options? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Exactly so. I suspect that your wireless device won't keep up when the channel is changed by the router. It is easy enough to change to test.

Comment: @chili555 The router was already set to a static channel, I will try with the channel width.